# get 0 value in php array

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array in php like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [post_date] => 2017-07-22 [num] => 1 )
        [1] => Array ( [post_date] => 2017-07-24 [num] => 2 )
        [2] => Array ( [post_date] => 2017-07-26 [num] => 5 ))
```

i want to change it to this array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [post_date] => 2017-07-22 [num] => 1 )
        [1] => Array ( [post_date] => 2017-07-23 [num] => 0 )
        [2] => Array ( [post_date] => 2017-07-24 [num] => 2 )
        [3] => Array ( [post_date] => 2017-07-25 [num] => 0 )
        [4] => Array ( [post_date] => 2017-07-26 [num] => 5 ))
```

how to do this?

Comment: And what you have tried?

Comment: I believe i have a more refined solution for your question, but i cannot post it while your question is on hold.  Please improve your question with the required details so that it can be re-opened.  (If it is ever reopened please ping me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code and hope it's clear enough, the idea behind this solution is very simple:

- First we sort our array using a user-defined comparison function by the `post_date` column value, this will helps us later when looping over the dates.
- After that we make sure that the array contains at least two value to compare by starting the `for` loop from `1` and make sure the size of the array is greater than `1`.If not we return the array as it is.

> $i = 1; $i < count($array);  => count($array) > 1 => at least 2
>   values.

- Next we calculate the difference between two consecutive `post_date` of the array, if the difference is `1 day` so we have two consecutive days, else we have to add the next day to the array from the "$i" position of `post_date` by using this helpers function:

> array_splice($array, $i, 0, [[
>           'post_date' => $date1->modify('+1 day')->format('Y-m-d'),
>           'num' => 0,
>       ]]);

Which will add 1 day the `post_date` and push other values to the right of the array which make the size of the array bigger ( +1 value) and will add another iteration for the for loop.

At the end of the loop, we will get a full array of consecutives days as the OP want.

```
<?php

$array = [
    ['post_date' => '2017-07-22','num' => '1'],
    ['post_date' => '2017-07-26','num' => '5'],
    ['post_date' => '2017-07-24','num' => '2'],
];

sort($array);

$count = count($array);

for($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $date1 = new DateTime($array[$i-1]['post_date']);
    $date2 = new DateTime($array[$i]['post_date']);
    $diff = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%a");

    if(1 < $diff) {
        array_splice($array, $i, 0, [[
            'post_date' => $date1->modify('+1 day')->format('Y-m-d'),
            'num' => 0,
        ]]);
        $count++;
    } 
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
```

the output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [post_date] => 2017-07-22
            [num] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [post_date] => 2017-07-23
            [num] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [post_date] => 2017-07-24
            [num] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [post_date] => 2017-07-25
            [num] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [post_date] => 2017-07-26
            [num] => 5
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope my post will be helpful, Here we are using `PHP` `Datetime`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/842007)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$array=
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'post_date' => '2017-07-22',
    'num' => '1',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'post_date' => '2017-07-24',
    'num' => '2',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'post_date' => '2017-07-26',
    'num' => '5',
  ),
);
$dates=  array_column($array, 'num','post_date');
$firstDate=$currentDate=key($dates);
end($dates);
$lastDate=key($dates);
$result=array();
while(true)
{
    if(isset($dates[$currentDate]))
    {
        $result[]=array('post_date'=>$currentDate,'num'=>$dates[$currentDate]);
    }
    else
    {
        $result[]=array('post_date'=>$currentDate,'num'=>0);
    }
    if($currentDate==$lastDate)
    {
        break;
    }
    $dateTimeObject= new DateTime($currentDate);
    $dateTimeObject->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
    $currentDate = $dateTimeObject->format("Y-m-d");
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.If the dates are not in order then also this code works. I have added comment in code for understanding

```
<?php
$array = array(
  array(
    "post_date"=>"2017-07-22",
    "num" =>1
    ),
  array(
    "post_date"=>"2017-07-24",
    "num" =>2
    ),
  array(
    "post_date"=>"2017-07-26",
    "num" =>5
    ),
  );
$total = count($array);
$check_dates = array_column($array, "post_date"); //array of dates
asort($check_dates); //sort array by dates and keep keys

$start_date = reset($check_dates); //minimum date
$end_date = end($check_dates); //maximum date

$current_date = $start_date; //set current date to start date
$new_array = array(); //this will be your final array
while (strtotime($current_date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
  $search_val = array_search($current_date, $check_dates);
  if($search_val > 0 || $search_val === 0)
  {
    $new_array[] = $array[$search_val];
  }
  else
  {
    $tmp_array=["post_date"=>$current_date,"num"=>0];
    $new_array[] = $tmp_array;
  }
  $current_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('+1 day',strtotime($current_date))); //change current date

}
print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define an array with the increased size which is capable of containing the whole dataset. You then could push all elements in it, and once you do that, using `strtotime`, you could sort the array to be as you wish.

```
<?php
    $arr1 = $your_initial_array;
    $arr2 = array_push($arr1, $your_values);
    $arr3 = array();
    $topop = 0;
    for($x = 0; $x < count($arr2); $x++) {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($arr2); $i++) {
            if(strtotime($arr2[$i]['post_date'] > $latest) { // or < if you want
                $topop = $i;
            }
        }
        array_push($arr3, $arr2[$topop]);
        unset($arr2[$topop]);
    }
```

You repeat it so many times your array contains elements to be sure you have the right succession. Hope this helps!